# Numpy arrays as image, image channels

Tags: python, image, numpy, machine-learning, keras

I have a 3D Image represented in numpy array format. Shape is (60, 60, 15) , 60 width 60 height 15 frames deep.

Now I want to process this image further with another library. But this library requires an argument "channels". https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv3d

What I don't get is how to find out how many channels my image has. 
Images are 3D MRI images: 
1 slice:

[image: example image]

Answer (score 1):

The channel represent usually the different colours used to code the image. For instance, in a RGB image, there is three channels: red, green and blue.

I guess your 3D image is coded with 1 channel (if each frame is code in Black & White) or 3 channels (if each frame is coded in colours).

Examples from the doc:

```
input_shape=(128, 128, 3) # for RGB pictures
input_shape=(128, 128, 128, 1) #  for 128x128x128 volumes with a single channel
```